# Logging message in 2 log files at the same time when assembly has log statement

Tags: file, log4net

I have a class library ABC where I have written logs using log4net.dll (Debug(),Error() methods). Path for log file is c:\abc\ab.log
Now, I am referring the ABC.dll to my project TestSample. In this project I am logging messages again. Path for log file is c:\testlogs\logfile.log
I am using log4net.dll 1.2.10 version for both projects.

Whenever I call methods of ABC.dll, it logs the messages in both log files.

Does anyone has solution to this?